# Removing the gradients from the Navigation Bar so it appears solid?

Tags: xcode, gradient, navbar

Is it possible to use tilt colour to make the nav bar appear solid? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so but you could just draw a 1 point solid image and set that:

A starting point for a category might look something like

```
- (void)ps_setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color;
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1, 1), YES, 1);

  [color setFill];
  CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1));
  UIImage *backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  [self setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

An example usage of the above would be

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar ps_setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```